# Can we include a Content Type within a content type in drupal 8

Tags: drupal

I am a newbie to Drupal 8.

In Drupal 8, I created a content type say "ABC" with few fields and I need to reuse the same content type i.e., "ABC" in another content type say "XYZ". Is this possible? Because I don't want to create same fields of a content type "ABC" to another content type "XYZ". I want to reuse this. Is it possible? If so, please suggest steps to do.

I know the concept of reusing the field but not content type. But, this is not helping me so please suggest some solution on this.

Thanks,
Pavithra

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form). With this module you can add content of a particular content type within another content type as an [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference).

Best regards